# Creating a mobile menu in jquery by toggleing a class and css transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some issues with jQuery not animating the mobile menu. I am trying to make it slide down and have the links in the menu slide in from the side or top. Right now its animating the links on the menu, but not the menu it self. It just appears and disappears. I have an .expanded class that has css transitions applied to it as well as the selector for the menu, but it still doesn't seem to be working as it was before.

[Website](http://52.7.237.185) (Shrink your window for the mobile menu)

[CSS](http://52.7.237.185/stylesheets/style.css) (towards the bottom in the media query)

[JS](http://52.7.237.185/javascripts/main.js)

Comment: Are you speaking of the hover animation?

Comment: @EmilBorconi I mean an animation that will cause the .menubutton div to expand down before the links show up and then have the links disappear before the menu contracts up again.

Comment: I think you will find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css looking at your code I think you are facing the same issue...

Comment: I think the approach he takes is better. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use bootstrap? Check this out http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html this page uses bootstrap that makes it responsive.

Comment: I prefer to do it on my own. I'm weening myself off of bootstrap.